# NodeJS not serving static html

Tags: html, node.js, express, static

I am having a problem serving my html file on my node server.

The code in "index.js" looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('views/home.html');
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Magic is happening on port 8081!');
});
```

Here is a picture of my file structure:

[image: File structure]

When i run the server, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

In the end i need a server that can serve several different pages, this is only the first page i am serving (no sense in going further if the first page doesn't work..)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about node.js, but try changing the path to `'/views/home.html'`

Comment: @Chrisstar, when i do that I get: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/views/home.html'.

Comment: please add screenshot of directory structure

Comment: What does happen? Do you see an error in the console. What does the browser show, what status code?

Comment: A side note: why do you write `path.join(__dirname + '/public')`,  it should be `path.join(__dirname, 'public')`

Comment: after You've added screenshot, answer is simple: simply`res.sendFile(__dirname + 'public/views/home.html');`

Comment: `In the end i need a server that can serve several different pages` in your question you show that `/` should serve `home.html` how should the other pages map from url to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i figured out a solution.

I changed the whole setup to this

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var port        = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var path        = require('path');
var http        = require('http');
var router      = express.Router();
//var data        = require('./routes/data');

// Setting the view engine and defining paths
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

require('./routes/routes')(app);

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server running on port ' + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is now working the way i wanted it to. Not sure if its optimal or perfect, but i think it does the job.

Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

For your dir structure your code must looks like

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'views'), {index: 'home.html'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

[Serving static files examples](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('views/home.html');
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Magic is happening on port 8081!');
});
```

You must have such dir structure:

```
views
  |-home.html
public
  |- some files here
index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation and the error tell you that `sendFile` that `[...]Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file[...]` ([res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html))

So you have to write:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/views/home.html'))
```

Comment: That works, but i was under the impression that there is a slightly other way to do it, considering that there will be several other pages in addition to the 'home.html' page.

Comment: @henrikbossart Well you wrote it that way in your question. Your question was not how to solve it for several other pages. But why your code does not serve that given file.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. i need this to work for several pages

Comment: @henrikbossart and how should it work? Currently `yourdomain.tld/view/home.html` would server that or any other file in that directory. If this is not that path you want to have, add another `express.static` e.g. with `path.join(__dirname, 'public/views/')` so that the path would be `yourdomain.tld/home.html`. But from the question it is not clear how the request path should correspond to the file that is served.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code, keep on html file in same folder, ex: index.html
in browser, localhost:9000/index.html

```
    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var port = 9000;

    //create server
    http.createServer(function(req,resp){
        reqUrl = req.url;
        var day = reqUrl.slice(1,reqUrl.length-1);
        file = reqUrl;
        callPage(req,resp,file);
    }).listen(port); 


    function callPage(req,resp,fileName){

        fileName = reqUrl.slice(1,reqUrl.length);
        console.log(fileName)
        fs.readFile(fileName,function(err,html){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            resp.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/html"});
            resp.write(html);
            resp.end();
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendations:

1) Move `views` folder to same location with `index.js`

2) Update code of `index.js`:

```
const 
    DEBUG_MODE = (process.env.DEBUG == 1),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

/* DEFINE VIEW RENDERER */
app.set('view cache', !DEBUG_MODE);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

/* DEFINE VIEW FILES LOCATION */
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

/* KEEP STATIC FILES IN SOME CONSTANT (GROUPED) PLACE, EX.: /assets */
app.use('/assets/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use('/assets/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));

/* RENDER home VIEW FOR ROOT REEQUEST */    
app.all('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'));

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Magic is happening on port 8081!');
});
```

serving view files is job of express app that is done by simply calling `res.render('view-name');` (without extension, cuz already defined in `app.engine('html', ...);`

P.S. If You need example: https://bitbucket.org/num8er/sum-az-website/src

Comment: Results in "Cannot GET /home.html"

Comment: @henrikbossart if You want frontend part that requests backend part for data, make 2 apps: frontend-app, backend-api